# How to make a certain element shortened in size after certain breakpoints (Tailwind css)

Tags: css, tailwind-css, element, breakpoints

So, Im new to react/web dev.

Just learnt the fundamentals of media-query,But I can't get my mind through this particular problem where in I want to change the size of the search container in the navbar to a another smaller element(magnifing glass), when the user switches from desktop to mobile version.

I have used  `<div class ="search invisible lg:visible">`but I cant figure how to replace the invisible with some other element.

#Code

This is the entire nav-bar.

```
            <div class = "flex text-white justify-start items-center">
                <div class = "hamburger-menu-container">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "github-icon-container">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-2xl"></i>
                </div>
                <div class = "dashboard-label-container">
                    <p class = "dash-font">Dashboard</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "flex items-center items-center justify-end">
                <div class = "search">
                    <i id = "magnifing-icon" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    <div class = "msg-search-nav">
                        <div class = "msg-search-desc text-sm text-white pr-40">Type / for search</div>
                    </div>
                    <img class = "palette-icon w-5 p-1" src={command_palette} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class = "flex nav-link items-center">
                    <i id = "plus-icon" class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    <select name="" id="select">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class = "nav-link">
                    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-regular fa-circle-dot"></i>
                </div>
                <div class  = "nav-link">
                    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-solid fa-code-pull-request"></i>
                </div>
                <div class ="nav-link">
                    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <img class="face-nav" src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/76707560?s=80&amp;v=4"/>
            </div>
```

```
                <div class = "search">
                    <i id = "magnifing-icon" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                    <div class = "msg-search-nav">
                        <div class = "msg-search-desc text-sm text-white pr-40">Type / for search</div>
                    </div>
                    <img class = "palette-icon w-5 p-1" src={command_palette} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class = "flex nav-link items-center">
                    <i id = "plus-icon" class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    <select name="" id="select">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

[image: The search box which needs to shorten to a magnifying glass]

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider applying `display: none` and `display: block` when you want to hide/show the element respectively. This would be more suitable for your case rather than `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` as `visibility: hidden` means the element still takes up layout space. This means when it is invisible, there could be some blank space behavior that you'd have to wrestle with.

For replacing with a more compact element, you could have another element that has the opposite `display` values:

```html
<div class="… hidden lg:block">
  …
</div>
<div class="block lg:hidden">
  …
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="flex text-white justify-start items-center">
  <div class="hamburger-menu-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="github-icon-container">
    <i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-2xl"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-label-container">
    <p class="dash-font">Dashboard</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex items-center items-center justify-end">
  <div class="search hidden lg:block">
    <i id="magnifing-icon" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
    <div class="msg-search-nav">
      <div class="msg-search-desc text-sm text-white pr-40">
        Type / for search
      </div>
    </div>
    <img class="palette-icon w-5 p-1" src="command_palette" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="block lg:hidden border rounded p-2">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="flex nav-link items-center">
    <i id="plus-icon" class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    <select name="" id="select">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-regular fa-circle-dot"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-solid fa-code-pull-request"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link">
    <i class="nav-link-icon fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
  </div>
  <img
    class="face-nav"
    src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/76707560?s=80&amp;v=4"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this may be it show work

Comment: I have used a little different approach just hard coded the media query in my css file specified the breakpoints explicitly.

Comment: # CSS code for search and magnifying content                                                                                                                                          
` @media (max-width : 1215px){
  .search{
    display : none;
  }
  .magnifing-container{
    display : block;
  } 
}

@media (min-width : 1215px){
  .search{
    display : flex;
  }
  .magnifing-container{
    display : none;
  }
}
`